# ZEND get email body

Tags: php, magento, email, zend-framework

Below is a function (it's from Magento) and the simple thing is... I want to get the email in a string. But somehow things like: `$mailer->getBodyText()->getRawContent()` and `$mail->getBodyHtml();` don't work...

At the bottom of this piece of code you'll find: `$SOMETHING_HERE` that is where I would like to get the body of the email.

```
public function sendNewOrderEmail()
{

    $storeId = $this->getStore()->getId();

    if (!Mage::helper('sales')->canSendNewOrderEmail($storeId)) {
        return $this;
    }
    // Get the destination email addresses to send copies to
    $copyTo = $this->_getEmails(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_TO);
    $copyMethod = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_METHOD, $storeId);

    // Start store emulation process
    $appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
    $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

    try {
        // Retrieve specified view block from appropriate design package (depends on emulated store)
        $paymentBlock = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($this->getPayment())
            ->setIsSecureMode(true);
        $paymentBlock->getMethod()->setStore($storeId);
        $paymentBlockHtml = $paymentBlock->toHtml();
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        // Stop store emulation process
        $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
        throw $exception;
    }

    // Stop store emulation process
    $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);

    // Retrieve corresponding email template id and customer name
    if ($this->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = $this->getBillingAddress()->getName();
    } else {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = $this->getCustomerName();
    }

    $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
    if($storeId!=1){
        $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
        $emailInfo->addTo($this->getCustomerEmail(), $customerName);
        if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'bcc') {
            // Add bcc to customer email
            foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
                $emailInfo->addBcc($email);
            }
        }
        $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
    }

    // Email copies are sent as separated emails if their copy method is 'copy'
    if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'copy') {
        foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
            $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
            $emailInfo->addTo($email);
            $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
        }
    }

    // Set all required params and send emails
    $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
    $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
    $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
    $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
            'order'        => $this,
            'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
        )
    );
    $mailer->send();

    //
    // edit, save to file
    //

    $fp = fopen("/var/www/magento/confirmations/".time().".html","w");
    fwrite($fp, $SOMETHING_HERE);
    fclose($fp);

    $this->setEmailSent(true);
    $this->_getResource()->saveAttribute($this, 'email_sent');

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mailer->getBodyText(true);
```

or

```
$mailer->getBodyHtml(true);
```

should work.